# j2ee service layer automated test cases

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, service, layer, testcase

I am working on Big Spring, ibatis, velocity bases J2EE project there are thousands of classes and number of service layer classes, i need to create test cases for all server layer classes is there any automated tool to write test cases for all service layer classes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no automated test case generator tool exists.

Answer (score 1):

No.

You need to figure out what you application does, split it up into components that are testable, and then write tests for those components.

Sorry.